# How to design API so it would fit REST conventions and Ember.js way?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, ember.js, ember-data

Would be a good practice to merge all properties of `Item`:

`{id: 1, priceId:1, property1:0}` with its corresponding `Price` `{id:1,seasonalPrice:123,regularPrice:120}` into:

`{id:1,property1:0, price:{seasonalPrice:123,regularPrice:120}}`.

Ember most likely can handle linking and combining(merging) two jsons that arrive as two promises from backend REST API into one model. What is the best approach to desing API and consume using Ember?

Comment: Ember itself has no standard around communicating with any API, you are likely curious about the Ember Data.  The JSON API is the current direction of the ember data team.

Comment: I run into a problem of trying to adapt json from backend to ember JSON API. It seems like an easier solution would be to ditch it in favor of AngularJS that doesn't require any custom Adapters and Serializers, has more examples and more popular - bigger community.

Comment: Ember itself doesn't require any custom adapters/serializers, you can use plain ol' ajax calls and json data.  Comparing a REST add-on to an mvc framework doesn't make any sense :)  You'd be better comparing restangular to ember-data, but then you're right back to custom adapters/serializers.

Answer (score 2):

For Rest API designing, you can read:

- [Rest In Practice](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805838.do)
- [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html)

You can apply Richardson Maturity Model level 2 or 3 with Ember Data.

With Ember, you can use any level that is suitable for your case. In our case we prefer to stay in level 1 with a strong backend (written in Java) and not to use Ember Data.